# ¿Cómo registrar una imagen por defecto en la base de datos cuando no se sube ninguna en el formulario?

Tags: php, formularios, imagen

Tengo un formulario para registrar en una base de datos de phpmyadmin, en este subo datos y una imagen, el formulario está hecho de tal forma que no sea necesario subir la imagen. Pero, el problema es que no e podido conseguir que cuando la persona que este llenando el formulario no suba imagen, se registre una por defecto en la base de datos o en su caso, que al imprimir el capo de la base de datos imprima una imagen por defecto, aquí el código con el que registro todo el formulario y la imágen:

```
    <?php

include("conexion.php"); 

$con=conectar();

    $usu=$_POST['usuario'];
        $contras=$_POST['contra'];
        $nombre1=$_POST['nombre1'];
        $nombre2=$_POST['nombre2'];
        $apellido1=$_POST['apellido1'];
        $apellido2=$_POST['apellido2'];
        $notel=$_POST['notel'];
        $email=$_POST['correo'];
        $tipou='Usuario';
        $e = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContenido = addslashes(file_get_contents($e));

$query="select * from login where usuario='$usu'"; 
$resulta=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if ((mysqli_num_rows($resulta)>0) ){
  echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n"; 
  echo "alert('Ya existe este nombre de usuario');\n"; 
  echo "</script>";
  echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=registrousu.php'>"; 
     mysqli_close($con);
    exit;
} else {
    
$Consulta= "INSERT INTO login (usuario,contra,nombre1,nombre2,apellido1,apellido2,notelefono,email,tipodeusuario,imagen) VALUES ('$usu','$contras','$nombre1','$nombre2','$apellido1','$apellido2','$notel','$email','$tipou','$imgContenido')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$Consulta);

echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n"; 
echo "alert('Usuario creado con Exito');\n"; 
echo "</script>";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=index.php'>"; 

}
 if($result==0){
   mysqli_close($con);
    exit;
 }



?>
```

Y aquí el código con el cual imprimo la imagen que está registrada en la base de datos:

```
<?php
                        $con=conectar();
                        $img = $_SESSION['usuario'];

                        $query="SELECT imagen FROM login WHERE usuario = '$img'"; 
                        $resulta=mysqli_query($con,$query);

                        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)) {
                        $img = $row['imagen'];
                      
                        
                      }
  
                    ?>

                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo  base64_encode($img); ?>">
```

Comment: Guardar una imagen por defecto me parece un despropósito. Yo guardaría null, y luego al consultar, si es null pongo una imagen desde algún archivo y en caso contrario pongo desde la que está en la base de datos.

Comment: De la forma que yo lo he hecho, en mi tabla, en el campo que tiene el nombre de la imagen tiene un valor por defecto, en mi caso, `notfound.png`. Cuando no se sube ninguna imagen el valor enviado es null, pero como tiene un valor por defecto sera `notfound.png`. Guardo una imagen con ese nombre (que ilustre graficamente que no se subio imagen) y de esta forma tiene una imagen por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

O podés hacer un condicional antes del insert sql, donde si no cargó imagen te agregue un path a la imagen genérica.

```
if($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']){
        $e = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContenido = addslashes(file_get_contents($e));
}else{
      $imgContenido = path.imagen.generica;
}
```

O podés hacer un condicional cuando mostras la imagen si no tiene o si es un campo null, que te muestra la generica predeterminada.

```
if ($row['imagen'] !='') {
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo  base64_encode($img); ?>">';
}else{
  echo '<img src=".$path.imagen.generica.">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puede realizar lo siguiente en tu base de datos

```
ALTER TABLE `perfil` CHANGE `imagen` `imagen` VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '/img/imagenDefaul.png';
```

cuando el usuario se registra en algunos campo puede colocar valores defaul